# Date format changing on VBA export from Outlook to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, date-format

This is a bit of strange one that's been doing my head in for the last few days.

I've been updating a macro in Outlook which exports details over to Excel.

So far the macro has been working fine, happily exporting the sender, subject and dates sent and received without a problem.

I've added in a bit so that I can capture the time and date if the email has been replied to/forwarded, but that's where things are going wrong.

When running the code, if I put a Debug.Print on the variable holding the reply/forwarded date it prints out in the correct format (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss), but when it pops over to excel for some reason it's being entered as mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss (but only for dates where the month is <= 12).

I've checked the computer's regional settings (in fact I've tried it on 2 different machines) and can't see anything that would cause the change.

The code I'm using is below, does anyone have any ideas?

```
'this is the part that exports to Excel
intColumnCounter = intColumnCounter + 1
Set rng = wks.Cells(intRowCounter, intColumnCounter)
rng.Value = GetLastVerb(msg)
Debug.Print GetLastVerb(msg)

Public Function GetLastVerb(olkMsg As Outlook.MailItem) As String
Dim intVerb As Integer
intVerb = GetProperty(olkMsg, "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003")
Select Case intVerb
    Case 102
        Debug.Print ("Reply to Sender")
        GetLastVerb = GetLastVerbTime(olkMsg)
    Case 103
        Debug.Print ("Reply to All")
        GetLastVerb = GetLastVerbTime(olkMsg)
    Case 104
     Debug.Print ("Forward")
        GetLastVerb = olkMsg.ReceivedTime
    Case 108
     Debug.Print ("Reply to Forward")
        GetLastVerb = GetLastVerbTime(olkMsg)
    Case Else
     Debug.Print ("Unknown")
        GetLastVerb = "Not replied to"
End Select
End Function

Public Function GetProperty(olkItm As Object, strPropName As String) As Date
Dim olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
Set olkPA = olkItm.PropertyAccessor
GetProperty = olkPA.UTCToLocalTime(olkPA.GetProperty(strPropName))
Set olkPA = Nothing
End Function

Public Function GetLastVerbTime(olkItm As Object) As Variant
GetLastVerbTime = GetDateProperty(olkItm, "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10820040")
End Function

Public Function GetDateProperty(olkItm As Object, strPropName As String) As Date
Dim olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
Set olkPA = olkItm.PropertyAccessor
GetDateProperty = olkPA.UTCToLocalTime(olkPA.GetProperty(strPropName))
Set olkPA = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because you are returning a string and vba will assume US format if possible-perhaps use

```
Dim sTemp as string
sTemp = GetLastVerb(msg)
if isdate(stemp) then 
   rng.Value = cdate(sTemp) 
else
   rng.value = sTemp
end if
```